# How do I select the top term buckets based on a rescore function in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, elasticsearch-5, relevance

Consider the following query for Elasticsearch 5.6:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "rescore": [
    {
      "window_size": 10000,
      "query": {
        "rescore_query": {
          "function_score": {
            "boost_mode": "replace",
            "script_score": {
              "script": {
                "source": "doc['topic_score'].value"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "query_weight": 0,
        "rescore_query_weight": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "distinct": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "identical_id",
        "order": {
          "top_score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "best_unique_result": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        },
        "top_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "_score"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a simplified version where the real query has a more complex main query and the rescore function is far more intensive.

Let me explain it's purpose first incase I'm about to spend a 1000 hours developing a pen that writes in space when a pencil would actually solve my problem. I'm performing a fast initial query, then rescoring the top results with a much more intensive function. From those results I want to show the top distinct values, i.e. no two results should have the same `identical_id`. If there's a better way to do this I'd also consider that an answer.

I expected a query like this would order results by the rescore query, group all the results that had the same `identical_id` and display the top hit for each such distinct group. I also assumed that since I'm ordering those term aggregation buckets by the max parent `_score`, they would be ordered to reflect the best result they contain as determined from the original rescore query.

The reality is that the term buckets are ordered by the maximum query score and not the rescore query score. Strangely the top hits within the buckets do seem to use the rescore.

Is there a better way to achieve the end result that I want, or some way I can fix this query to work the way I expect it too?

Comment: The problem is not in the top hits as it has been solved here (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19317). It is more that the terms aggregation or the max one is using the initial score and not the rescored one in the "top_score" section. It might be a technical limit, a bug or a wish.
Note that inside the top hits aggregation, the hits are suddenly sorted by rescore hits !

Comment: Elastic Search also offers a collapse function (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html) that does the distinct in a more expressive way. There was a try to make the collapse function compatible with the re-scoring but it has been reverted for low level problem (more here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/28521#issuecomment-377522283). Might be good to keep an eye on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a pretty great solution to this problem, but I'll let the bounty continue to expiration incase someone comes up with a better approach.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sample": {
      "sampler": {
        "shard_size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "identical_id",
            "order": {
              "top_score": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "best_unique_result": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "_script": {
                      "type": "number",
                      "script": {
                        "source": "doc['topic_score'].value"
                      },
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "top_score": {
              "max": {
                "script": {
                  "source": "doc['topic_score'].value"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `sampler` aggregation will take the top N hits per shard from the core query and run aggregations over those. Then in the max aggregator that defines the bucket order I use the exact same script as the one I use to pick a top hit from the bucket. Now the buckets and the top hits are running over the same top N sets of items and the buckets will order by the max of the same score, generated from the same script. Unfortunately I still need run the script once to order the buckets and once to pick a top hit within the bucket, and you could use the rescore instead for the top hits ordering, but either way it has to run twice and I found it was faster as a sort script then as a rescore

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-rescore.html) :

> The query rescorer executes a second query only on the Top-K results **returned by the query and post_filter phases**. The number of docs which will be examined on each shard can be controlled by the window_size parameter, which defaults to 10.

As the `rescore query` kicks in after the `post_filter` phase, I assume the term aggregation buckets are already fixed.

I have no idea on how you can combine rescore and aggregations. Sorry :(

Comment: Thanks, at this point I might try and build a plugin to take the top 10K results as IDs from the main query then run a second query just on those IDs with the more intensive score function and the aggregations. Building it as a plugin mitigates some of the overhead of moving all those IDs around.

Comment: check out my answer, I think I found a solution!

Comment: just in case, did you try a function score query with field value vector? (see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor ) . You could just filter your document with the main query, and use the function score query to get your custom score

Comment: The script that I'm using in the example could be replaced with a function score / field value vector. This is only a simplified version of my real query though. My really query uses a plugin and the script through that plugin is actually calculating vector similarity between high dimensional vectors stored on each document.